# JavaScript and JSON: outputting different values in different tables

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting JSON data from a file, and then trying to display the values from one name in one table and the values from another name in another table, but all the data is in both tables.

I cannot figure out how to isolate the values from one name and another in each table.

Here is my JSON:

```
{"launch_3d_link":"<a href='content/3d/speedswing1.html' target='ifrm'>Speed Swing 1</a>"},
{"launch_3d_link":"<a href='content/3d/speedswing2.html' target='ifrm'>Speed Swing 2</a>"},
{"launch_3d_link":"<a href='content/3d/speedswing3.html' target='ifrm'>Speed Swing 3</a>"},
{"launch_anim_link":"<a href='content/animated/animated1.html' target='ifrm'>Animated 1</a>"},
{"launch_anim_link":"<a href='content/animated/animated2.html' target='ifrm'>Animated 2</a>"},
{"launch_anim_link":"<a href='content/animated/animated3.html' target='ifrm'>Animated 3</a>"}
```

Here is my JavaScript (in header):

```
function loadFilesJson(data){
    $.getJSON(url = 'lists/files.json',
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Here are my Tables:

```
<div id="3d" class="panel">
    <table id="3d" width="100%" style="margin-left:-15px;">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON(url,
            function (data) {
                var tr;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].launch_3d_link + "</td>");
                    $('#3d').append(tr);
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
    </table>
</div>
```

and:

```
<div class="panel">
    <table id="anim" width="100%" style="margin-left:-15px;">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON(url,
            function (data) {
                var tr;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].launch_anim_link + "</td>");
                    $('#anim').append(tr);
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
    </table>
</div>
```

Small Update: I have changed my 'table' ID's to be unique. Code updated above.

Comment: `launch_3d_link` does not exist for some records and `launch_anim_link` doesn't exist on the others. So do you get 'undefined' on each table for the records not having the key used on that table?

Comment: Check your ``$('table')`` selector - doesn't it select both tables?

Comment: @MarcCompte: Correct, I get undefined for each name/value pair not found with that name. For the data above, I get the correct 3 iterations of Speed Swing, 6 Undefined, then the 3 correct iterations of Animated.

Comment: Your JSON doesn't look valid. If it's supposed to be an array, it needs to have `[ ]` around it.

Comment: @Barmar My JSOn is encapsulated with [] in my file, if it wasn't I would not even be getting any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things.

First, like Tibo said, you should reference each table uniquely. The selector `$('table')` means it will add the current `TR` to any table on your site. Give an `id` to each table (like you have in the first case, 3d), and then select it directly.

```
<div id="3d" class="panel">
   ...
</div>

<div id="anim" class="panel">
   ...
</div>
```

Then you should also check if the attribute key exists in the current record. Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (typeof data[i].launch_anim_link != 'undefined') {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].launch_anim_link + "</td>");
        $('#anim table').append(tr);
    }
}
```

If launch_anim_link does not exist it will skip it.

The same for the other table, but with `launch_3d_link` instead and selecting the proper table `$('#3d table').append(tr)`.

Comment: Thanks very much to both you and Tibo for your help. This is working perfectly now. The update from Tibo made me realise I had not uniquely identified my tables, while you help let me understand how to filter out unwanted values. I've never had to take this approach before.